# Confusion in Definition of separable polynomials

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

**Definition -1:** Any polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ is called separable if all the irreducible factors of $f(x)$ are separable.
**Definition -1** is from 'Pearson' publication Modern Algebra
and **Definition-2** is from 'Dummit and Foote'.

**Definition -2:** A polynomial is said to be separable over $F$ if it has no multiple roots( i.e., all its roots are distinct).

According to **Definition -1** $f(x)=(x-2)^3(x^2-2)$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ is separable.
But this example contradicts the **Definition -2.**

Am I wrong some where? Or the definition of book is wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Definition 1 seems circular to me.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Is the 'definition 1' wrong?

Comment: @Unknown Well, it defines "separable" in terms of "separable" - presumably beforehand the text has defined what it means for an irreducible polynomial to be separable?